# How do I show what specific Power Scheme I am in?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using AutoHotkey and it's a neat piece of software to learn Scripting. But what I'm trying to do is how would I look up what power plan I am in and have it output into a MsgBox?

The below code is what I already have, but would like to add the above to it.

```
^+1::
RunWait, %comspec% /c "powercfg.exe /setactive 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c",, Hide
MsgBox, Your Power Plan is now in: HighPerformance
return

^+2::
RunWait, %comspec% /c "powercfg.exe /setactive 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e",, Hide
MsgBox, Your Power Plan is now in: Balanced Mode
```

Comment: Please decide on whether you want [tag:AutoHotKey] help or [tag:Batch-File] help and edit your chosen tags accordingly. To find out how a command works you'd use the help option `/?` at the Command Prompt, i.e. `PowerCfg /?` where you'd clearly see the `GetActiveScheme` option. `PowerCfg /GetActiveScheme`.

Answer (score 0):

In AHK you can try this:

```
RegRead, power_plan, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel\NameSpace\{025A5937-A6BE-4686-A844-36FE4BEC8B6D}, PreferredPlan
If (power_plan  = "381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e")
    MsgBox, Your Power Plan is: Balanced Mode
else
If (power_plan  = "38c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c")
    MsgBox, Your Power Plan is: HighPerformance
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/935799/when-you-configure-power-options-for-the-active-power-plan-in-windows

Probably you have to run the script as administrator.